# Getting files from SVN by maintaining the Folder Structure

Tags: svn, batch-file

Is it possible to get files from SVN (using svn command) by maintaining the exact folder structure? 
Currently I'm using the following command to get the files from SVN which are modified within a particular date.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>svn log http://10.32.10.56/svn/Project/main -v -r `{2011-03-25}:{2011-03-29} --xml > test.xml`
```

This writes the output to test.xml file. Now I parse this XML file and `export` the files from SVN. I'm using the following command for that

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>svn export http://10.32.10.56/svn/Project/main/ProjectName/src/com/test/Test.java  --depth empty
```

This returns me just the file. **Is it possible to get the file by maintaining the folder structure?** I think checkout can do this. But it seems to return all the files in the mentioned folder.

I found lot of links which gets the files from SVN within a date range. But none of them worked for me. That is the reason why I'm using the above approach. Please let me know if there is a better approach to get the files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're really trying to do here, but you might be able to combine both steps into a single svn export -r with your date range.  If that doesn't work,  then on your second command snippet, try leaving off the --depth empty from the end of it.

Comment: Hi Randy, Thanks for the reply. I need to get the files that are modified in a particular date range. I don't have that list with me(list of files that are modified). So I thought I will get that list first and then get the files from SVN.

Comment: @Apps: I messed with this a bit, and nothing I tried worked very well.  svn co and export don't allow the date range, so probably your two-stage approach is your best bet.  Since you're already parsing the file list from the log, you could extract the portion of the path you want and do a mkdir -p <extracted path> before the svn export.

Comment: Even I was also thinking about that approach. I just wanted to know if there was any better approach. Thank you so much for your help.